# how do I get the value of a list outside the asynchronous method?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I've done a search on another stackoverflow post for 2 hours but still can not solve this problem. I have a variable called `copyAudioListIqro` with List String datatype in `DetailMemilihIqro` Activity class. When the variable called `audioIqros` in the AsyncTask class (precisely in the onPostExecute method) **this list has a value from my json** and I want to copy `audioIqros` variable to `copyAudioListIqro` via **updateData method (outside the asynctask class)**. When I see the log monitor on **updateData** method I can see the value from `copyAudioListIqro`, but the problem is, when I access it via **readDataAudioURL method(outside the asynctask class)** `copyAudioListIqro` variable becomes null.

What is the solution for this problem? 
Thank you

Here is the overall DetailMemilihIqro class

```
public class DetailMemilhIqro extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<ModelAudioIqro> audioIqros;
    private List<String> copyAudioListIqro;
    private AudioAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private String TAG = DetailMemilihIqro.class.getSimpleName();
    Context context;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_memilih_iqro);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvCVAudioIqro);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        audioIqros = new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new AudioAdapter(getApplicationContext(), audioIqros);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        copyAudioListIqro = new ArrayList<>();


        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        Bundle getPosition = getIntent().getExtras();
        int position = getPosition.getInt("positionUserClicked");
        Log.d(TAG, "Position User clicked " + position);

        if (position == 0) {
            String endpoint = "http://latihcoding.com/jsonfile/audioiqro1.json";

            new DownloadTask().execute(endpoint);


        } else if (position == 1) {
            String endpoint = "http://latihcoding.com/jsonfile/audioiqro2.json";
            new DownloadTask().execute(endpoint);


        } else if (position == 2) {
            String endpoint = "http://latihcoding.com/jsonfile/audioiqro3.json";
            new DownloadTask().execute(endpoint);

        }

        readDataAudioURL();

    }

    public void updateData(List<String> pathUrl) {

        for (int i = 0; i < pathUrl.size(); i++) copyAudioListIqro.add(pathUrl.get(i));
        Log.d(TAG, "updateData Method " + copyAudioListIqro.toString());

    }

    public void readDataAudioURL() {
        Log.d(TAG, "readDataAudioURL Method " + copyAudioListIqro.toString());
    }

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>> {

        List<String> modelAudioIqroList;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog.setMessage("Downloading json...");
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(String... strings) {
            modelAudioIqroList = new ArrayList<>();
            int result;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                // 200 represents HTTP OK
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(line);
                    }
                    parseResult(response.toString());
                    result = 1; // Successful
                    Log.d(TAG, "Result " + result);

                } else {
                    //"Failed to fetch data!";
                    result = 0;
                    Log.d(TAG, "Result " + result);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            return modelAudioIqroList; //"Failed to fetch data!";

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> audioIqros) {
            super.onPostExecute(audioIqros);
            pDialog.hide();
            if (!audioIqros.isEmpty()) {
                updateData(modelAudioIqroList);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        private void parseResult(String result) {
            try {
                JSONArray response = new JSONArray(result);

                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    ModelAudioIqro modelAudioIqro = new ModelAudioIqro();
                    modelAudioIqro.setName(object.getString("name"));
                    modelAudioIqro.setUrl(object.getString("url"));
                    String path = modelAudioIqro.getUrl();
                    Log.d(TAG, "String path " + path);

                    modelAudioIqroList.add(path);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

}
```

[Log for the copyAudioListIqro in the **updateDataMethod**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkLYB.png)

[Log for the copyAudioListIqro in the **readDataAudioURL**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vj38k.png)

Comment: `updateDataMethod` is called only when the downloading is done, however `readDataAudioURL` is called right after you _start_ executing the download task, at which point the variable has not been copied.

Comment: I understand what you mean but I am confused when implementing the code. Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with Android development, that's why I didn't post an answer :-). But basically what @Shine just answered - do what you want to do with the list within `postExecute`.

Answer (score 0):

`readDataAudioURL()` call, that is a plain Log call, should be moved. Infact the task is *asynch* by nature, so oblivously the variable `copyAudioListIqro` won't have been initialized right after the task's start (`.execute()` method).

You're doing right, anyway, in notyfiying dataset change to list...You should just move it to postExecute as well...

I suggest to move all "after network" code to that **`postExecute`**, so that UI can be updated asynchronously ONLY when data is available and without blocking main thread. You can 'read' variables in the inner class, so just declare them final:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> audioIqros) {
        super.onPostExecute(audioIqros);
        pDialog.hide();
        if (!audioIqros.isEmpty()) {
            updateData(modelAudioIqroList);
            //data is now updated, notify datasets and/or send broadcast
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            readDataAudioURL();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

A more elaborate pattern would include broadcast receiver and intents, but I guess this is out of this question's scope.

Comment: I tried the code that you created but the log is still null. Is there another way to get the value from the list? so it can be used from outside asynctask

Comment: how can it be null, if you're printing inside same asynchtask's scope? Just move the call

Comment: Yep, inside the asynctask class the variable `copyAudioListIqro` has the value. But the main problem on my question, when I access the `copyAudioListIqro` variable from outside the asynctask the `copyAudioListIqro` is null.